# Export from BigQuery using tabledata: list is slow

Tags: export, google-bigquery

I have written a simple Java application to export tables from Google BigQuery using the tabledata: list method (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tabledata/list) and using pageToken for paging. No matter what I set the maxResults parameter to, I can only retrieve about 5000 lines per request (depending on row size). As requests take several seconds, this way I can only download 100mb per minute on average.

The ways I have found to speed this up so far:

**Batch** (not good in my case)

- batch export to Google Cloud Storage

**Parallelising requests**

- using startIndex
- using dynamic table partitions

It seems the most performant way for my use case is last option, combined with the snapshot decorator to get a stable result in case of changing tables:

```
myproject:mydataset.mytable@timestamp$0-of-3
myproject:mydataset.mytable@timestamp$1-of-3
myproject:mydataset.mytable@timestamp$2-of-3
```

So my questions are:

1. Is there a better (=faster) approach
2. Do the tabledata list request count against the limit of 50 concurrent requests

Answer (score 0):

You can first Export a BigQuery table to Google Cloud Storage using [configuration.extract](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#resource-representations) property of [Jobs: insert](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/insert)

Then you can download file to location of your interest

Comment: Hi Mikhail, you mean exporting to Cloud Storage is faster than listing table data partitions in parallel?

Comment: check out - Exporting data into one or more files - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/exporting-data-from-bigquery#exportingmultiple